# Angular JS - Login screen shown on page Refresh (F5) of application

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, page-refresh

In Angular SPA application, login screen is show/hide based on ng-show directive variable which is in $rootScope.

If user is in home page and refresh the page (F5), Login screen is shown as Complete page is refreshed and lost root scope variable value.

How to fix this issue?

Code Sample::

```
<body ng-controller="mainController">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="schoolLoginCtrl"
        ng-show="showLogin">
        <form class="form-signin" ng-submit="login()">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login Page</h2>
            <label for="userName" class="sr-only">User Name</label> <input
                type="text" id="userName" ng-model="user.userName"
                class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label> <input
                type="password" id="inputPassword" ng-model="user.password"
                class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{errorMsg}}</div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign
                in</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="container" ng-show="!showLogin">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>


.controller('mainController', function($scope, $rootScope,
        $location) {
    $rootScope.showLogin = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ngcookie or pouchdb or localstorage to store user session

this can help you https://github.com/sahat/satellizer

Comment: This worked for me Steps I followed.  
1)<script src="js/lib/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>  
2)add 'ngCookies' angular module  
3) add  $cookies to controller  
4)  if ($cookies.get('showLogin') !== undefined) {  
   console.log("update cookie");  
   $rootScope.showLogin = $cookies.get('showLogin');  
   $cookies.put('showLogin', $cookies.get('showLogin'));  
  } else {  
   $rootScope.showLogin = true;  
   console.log("add cookie");  
   $cookies.put('showLogin', true);  
  }

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement some type of stateful storage functionality. This can be accomplished using [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) or local storage (there are many 3rd party implementations of this).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you refresh the page, all the javascripts and other resources are loaded again and so the angularjs, which will basically re-initialize the `$rootScope` with its initial value and everything bind to it will be lost.

I will suggest to use the web storage(local/session storage) or cookies as per your use cases and requirements.